# Jquery Mobile dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I started learning Jquery mobile, I followed this http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/string.html. Nothing happens when I click the button.  The code I wrote is :

```
 <link rel= "stylesheet" href= "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
<script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src= "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).delegate('#simplestring', 'click', function() {
     $(this).simpledialog({
     'mode' : 'string',
      'prompt' : 'What do you say?',
     'buttons' : {
      'OK': {
      click: function () {
       $('#dialogoutput').text($('#dialoglink').attr('data-string'));
      }
      },
      'Cancel': {
       click: function () { },
        icon: "delete",
        theme: "c"
        }
        }
         })
        })
 </script>
```

Then within the body I wrote :

```
      <p>You have entered: <span id="dialogoutput"></span></p>
     <a href="#" id="dialoglink" data-role="button">Open Dialog</a>
```

Could you please point to my error? Maybe in the header ? I have to learn jquery mobile because I wrote a dialog box in javascript that won't show up in my Webapp. I read that the SimpleDialog in JQM aims to be a replacement for javascript dialog().

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/css/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).delegate('#simplestring', 'click', function () {
    $(this).simpledialog({
        'mode': 'string',
        'prompt': 'What do you say?',
        'cleanOnClose': true,
        'buttons': {
            'OK': {
                click: function () {
                    $('#simplestringout').text($('#simplestring').attr('data-string'));
                }
            },
            'Cancel': {
                click: function () {
                    console.log(this);
                },
                icon: "delete",
                theme: "c"
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>
<a href="#" id="simplestring" data-role="button">Open Dialog</a>
</body>
</html>
```